How to get Zones and spaces of an ifc model in autodesk forge viewer
I am using Autodesk forge viewer for loading ifc model.
In the model tree iam getting the model hierarchy.Iam not able  to see spaces and Zones in the model tree,but iam getting Ifc spaces.
iam using the below version
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

I want to get Zones and spaces of the loaded ifc model.please help me how to get that
Thanks in advance.

As far as I know, spaces/zones are not extracted by the Model Derivative service by default. This information is only extracted in selected workflows, for example:

when converting a Revit design with the generateMasterViews option
when converting Navisworks designs

An alternative approach would be extracting the IFC spaces/zones using a custom Revit plugin: https://github.com/jeremytammik/IfcSpaceZoneBoundaries. We built a prototype couple years ago where this plugin was deployed to the Design Automation service.
